# Prompting user when form fields have changed and they do not save

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty common scenario here, a user changes fields in a form and leaves the page without saving. I throw a warning message.

I first began with using

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){ });
```

But I want to throw a Dialog and give the user some options, I opted for this instead.

```
$("#myForm").change( function(){
    $("a:not(:#myForm a)").click( function(){
    $("#promptDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

The only scenario in which this doesn't accurately work is when the user changes a field, then changes it back to it's original value (It shouldn't prompt, but does).

Is this solution elegant, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the onbeforeunload-part is hard to replace, there are still other ways to leave a page than clicking a link, and you can't intercept all of them.

But the issue with the change-event can be handled a better way.

On DOMready store the initial values of the form somewhere, e.g. inside the form's data.

On beforeunload you may compare the stored values and the current values to determine if there have been any changes:

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {

    $('#myForm').data('defaultValues',$('#myForm').serialize());

    $(window)
      .on('beforeunload',
          function()
          {
            if($('#myForm').data('defaultValues')!=$('#myForm').serialize())
            {
              return 'are you sure?';
            }
          });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the implementation features of the browser. You want to exchange the standard alert (an implementation-defined construct) for your custom dialog, which you can't do in the `onbeforeunload` function. Your latter solution should suffice as a substitute.

Comment: Heh, sorry just wrote that up quick - but same difference. I will correct that though. Is there a way to escape the default behavior of the browser which throws the alert box and instead throw a Dialog? Or is my latter solution viable?

Comment: No, sorry, you can't do that. `onbeforeunload` runs only on a string return value.

Comment: I thought so - meh, so I am back with attaching click events to all anchor tags which are not part of the actual form functionality.